# How to have a different name for an object on every loop

Tags: java, loops, object

I'm trying to create a variable number of objects and add them to a hashMap using a while loop. However, i want each object to have a different name and I do not know how to do it.

This is my code:

```
public void petrolStation(int amountOfPumps)
{
       private HashMap<Integer, Pump> pumps = new HashMap<>();
       int i = 0;
       while(i <= amountOfPumps)
       {
             Pump p1 = new Pump();
             pumps.put(i, p1);
             i++;
       }
}
```

So what I can't figure out is instead of having 'p1' on every loop, have a different name on every loop.

Comment: `p1` is independent of any object at each iteration. it's just an identifier.

Comment: p1 is only the variable name and it's only known inside the scope of your loop. Nothing in the resulting ``HashMap`` knows anything by the name of ``p1``.

Comment: You don't need a variable at all: `pumps.put(i, new Pump());`. And you should use a `for` loop.

Comment: Objects don't have "names", unless you're talking about a name property of the object, in which case you'd likely have a `setName(String name)` method or a String name parameter in the constructor. If on the other hand you're talking about variable names, then you're confusing reference variable with object/reference, and will need to study on the differences between the two.

Comment: Generally, we measure gasoline in gallons (or liters). How many "pumps" to the gallon?

Comment: The example I would use to demonstrate why variables' names don't mean anything is: `Pump p1 = new Pump(); Pump p2 = p1;` Now: `p2` and `p1` are the same object; but if an object only has one name, which would it be?

Comment: Oh i always though objects had to have different identifiers otherwise it would be the same, thanks.

Comment: Heck no. In fact often an object may be associated with **many** identifiers, and in that situation, which one represents the object's "name"? e.g., `Foo f1 = new Foo();` `Foo f2 = f1;`. Both f1 and f2 refer to the **same** Foo object.

Comment: Elliott Frisch Are you thinking that pump is used as a unit of measurement for volume rather than a fuel dispenser?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`p1` is a new object at each iteration of the while loop, there is no relationship between any object created in one iteration and another. `p1` is simply an identifier to an object created in heap memory.

if you don't want to use the identifier `p1`(for some reason) then you can do:

```
pumps.put(i, new Pump());
```

rather than:

```
Pump p1 = new Pump();
pumps.put(i, p1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some very complicated patterns with the reflection API how you could dynamically generate identifiers during runtime, however, this hardly makes any sense.

Instead, you should identify your objects with the key you used to put them on the map. Maps are an excellent way to handle a dynamically generated amount of objects. So instead of later on refering to p1, p2, p3 you write pumps.get(1), pumps.get(2), pumps.get(3)...

Also note that your indexing is off. Either start with i = 1 or terminate with i < amountOfPumps (unless you actually want one more object than pumps).